# ASP.NET Optimization not transforming LESS into CSS

Tags: .net, less, asp.net-optimization, bundling-and-minification

I'm having difficulty getting LESS files to be transformed to CSS using .NET's new Optimization Framework (for minification and bundling).

I have a directory which contains only LESS files.

I use the following code to bundle these together and transform them into CSS:

```
var lessBundle = new Bundle("~/st-style-common-2")
    .IncludeDirectory("~/Admin/Resources/styles/", "*.less");
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new LessTransform());
lessBundle.Transforms.Add(new CssMinify());
bundles.Add(lessBundle);
```

I've also used the LessTransform class that is detailed [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification).

When debug="false" the files are transformed into standard CSS and compiled into one, as expected.

However, when debug="true" the files are not transformed, leaving a bunch of .less URLs in the HTML, which the browser doesn't understand and IIS doesn't appear to have a handler for.

I realise that I *could* build some handler that would serve these .less files but I don't believe that I should need to. Doesn't the Optimization Framework convert LESS to CSS even while debugging?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I didn't find a solution, *per se*, but I managed to get around this problem by using the [Web Essentials plug-in](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/07d54d12-7133-4e15-becb-6f451ea3bea6?SRC=Home) which automatically converts my LESS files to CSS (as well as a minified CSS version).

This allows me to work with LESS, save the file and have a CSS version of the styling automatically compiled, and then I simply reference the CSS versions rather than the LESS versions:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/styles").Include(
            "~/Admin/Resources/styles/*.css"));
```

Comment: you need to add .less handler in you web.config `<system.web>
<httpHandlers>
<add path="*.less" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" validate="false" />`
...
`<system.webServer>
<handlers>
             <add path="*.less" name="dotless" verb="GET" type="dotless.Core.LessCssHttpHandler,dotless.Core" resourceType="File" preCondition="" />` assuming you have [dotless](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) package installed

Answer (score 2):

Step 2 in [the tutorial you mentioned](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification) where you got the LessTransform class from, says you should install the dotless NuGet package. When you do so through the Visual Studio Package Manager, a .less handler gets registered in your Web.config automatically. It is important that the following is in the Web.config too:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
```

That way everything will work automatically, and your development team can work with the project even if they didn't have Web Essentials installed. I don't like having a dependency on some extension to be able to work with a project (even though I love Web Essentials!)

Comment: That's a good point, thanks. At this stage I'm too far past the solution to go back and re-work what you suggested, but hopefully it'll be useful for some future readers of this post.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that optimizations are not run by default when debug=true, for less files you always want to run optimizations so you can explicitly set this by setting in your BundleConfig.cs:

```
BundleTable.Bundles.EnableOptimizations = true
```

Comment: This will not only transform the .LESS, but also potentially minifies and bundles CSS and javascript, which you probably don't want while debugging (especially when debugging javascript).

Comment: BundleTable.EnableOptimizations